# Can't define task dependencies between multiple projects using gradle

Tags: gradle

I need to build 2 projects using Gradle.
I have the 2 gradle files for each project and a parent gradle file.
In the settings.gradle I define the projects:

```
include 'loadRemote'
include 'load'
rootProject.name = 'EquipLoad'

project(':loadRemote').buildFileName = 'buildRemote.gradle'
project(':load').buildFileName = 'buildLoad.gradle'
```

Each of the subprojects has their own defined compile and stage tasks.
I need the loadRemote project to run first then the load project.
How to I create this dependency?
I tried adding the dependency to the build.gradle file like this:

```
tasks.getByPath(":load:cleanCompileStage").dependsOn(":loadRemote:cleanCompileStage")
```

But the load project compiles first.

I found these syntax:

```
project(':load') {
    dependencies {
       compile project (':remoteLoad')
    }
}
```

But need to replace the Gradle `compile` task with the one that I created in the subproject.  I am not sure if it is allowed.

Does anyone have any ideas how to define the dependencies of tasks between 2 subprojects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answer did not work for me.  I'm sure it is unique to my project.  I have to create 2 ear files using 1 code base.

What I did was create a parent gradle file, build.gradle, and add tasks in there that used both projects like this:

```
//This task builds load and loadRemote ear using 1 command, buildAll
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    task compileAll (dependsOn: [project(':loadRemote').remoteLoadCleanCompileStage]) {
         compileAll.finalizedBy project(':load').loadCleanCompileStage
    }

    task packageAll (dependsOn: [project(':loadRemote').remoteLoadPackage]) {
        packageAll.finalizedBy project(':load').loadPackage
    }

    task buildAll (dependsOn: [compileAll]) {
        buildAll.finalizedBy packageAll
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your script like this:

```
project(':load') {
   war.dependsOn project(":loadRemote").tasks.compileJava
}
```

Comment: I get the error **Could not get unknown property 'war' for project ':load' of type org.gradle.api.Project.**

Comment: Added the **war** plugin but it is still compiling the **load** project before the **remoteLoad**

Comment: In the dependencies of the load you need to keep this script , same as you have mentioned. 
`project(':load ') {
    apply plugin:'java'
 dependencies {
    compile project(':load')
 }
 }`
Obviously this is allowed in gradle.As compilation of a project should depend on other project during execution phase.